# TreeView Java FX: hide a node

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, java-8

Is it possible to hide a node in a tree View (the same way it works for Root) without having to remove the node from the tree itself ? The aim is to be able to provide a filter and a "show/hide" option on certain item of the tree.

All help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind the cell `visibleProprerty` to an external boolean property, since the `VirtualFlow` will manage the cells on its own, setting its visibility to true when required, regardless of your settings.

As an alternative, you can disable the cell or you can make it not visible by setting its opacity to 0, but there will be a blank gap of the size of the cell.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27125863/3956070) shows you how to disable single cells. To change the opacity, just add an `opacityProperty` to the `Wrap` class, or create a binding :

```
    // disable cell
        cell.disableProperty().bind(wrap.disabledProperty());

    // or "hide" cell with blank gap
        // - with new property in Wrap
        cell.opacityProperty().bind(wrap.opacityProperty());
        // - with a Binding
        cell.opacityProperty().bind(
            Bindings.createDoubleBinding(()->wrap.disabledProperty().get()?0d:1d,
                    wrap.disabledProperty()));
```

Answer (score 7):

I found this [article](http://www.kware.net/?p=204) by Christoph Keimel which I think should solve your problem.

Basically you can't do it without a hack.
You can have a FilterableTreeItem which extends TreeItem in which you create a FilteredList.

```
public class FilterableTreeItem<T> extends TreeItem<T> {
private final ObservableList<TreeItem<T>> sourceList;

private final ObjectProperty<TreeItemPredicate<T>> predicate = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

public FilterableTreeItem(T value) {
    super(value);
    sourceList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    FilteredList<TreeItem<T>> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(sourceList);

    filteredList.predicateProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
        return child -> {
            // Set the predicate of child items to force filtering
            if (child instanceof FilterableTreeItem) {
                FilterableTreeItem<T> filterableChild = (FilterableTreeItem<T>) child;
                filterableChild.setPredicate(predicate.get());
            }
            // If there is no predicate, keep this tree item
            if (predicate.get() == null) {
                return true;
            }
            // If there are children, keep this tree item
            if (!child.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            }
            // Otherwise ask the TreeItemPredicate
            return predicate.get().test(this, child.getValue());
        };
    }, predicate));

    setHiddenFieldChildren(filteredList);
}

/**
 * Set the hidden private field {@link TreeItem#children} through reflection and hook the hidden {@link ListChangeListener} in {@link TreeItem#childrenListener} to the list
 * 
 */
protected void setHiddenFieldChildren(ObservableList<TreeItem<T>> list) {
    Field children = ReflectionUtils.findField(getClass(), "children");
    children.setAccessible(true);
    ReflectionUtils.setField(children, this, list);

    Field childrenListener1 = ReflectionUtils.findField(getClass(), "childrenListener");
    childrenListener1.setAccessible(true);
    Object childrenListener = ReflectionUtils.getField(childrenListener1, this);

    list.addListener((ListChangeListener<? super TreeItem<T>>) childrenListener);
}

/**
 * Returns the list of children that is backing the filtered list.
 * 
 * @return underlying list of children
 */
public ObservableList<TreeItem<T>> getInternalChildren() {
    return sourceList;
}

public final ObjectProperty<TreeItemPredicate<T>> predicateProperty() {
    return predicate;
}

public final TreeItemPredicate<T> getPredicate() {
    return predicate.get();
}

public final void setPredicate(TreeItemPredicate<T> predicate) {
    this.predicate.set(predicate);
}
```

}

You will also need the TreeItemPredicate

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TreeItemPredicate<T> {
/**
 * Utility method to create a TreeItemPredicate from a given {@link Predicate}
 */
static <T> TreeItemPredicate<T> create(Predicate<T> predicate) {
    return (parent, value) -> predicate.test(value);
}

/**
 * Evaluates this predicate on the given argument.
 *
 * @param parent
 *            the parent tree item of the element or null if there is no
 *            parent
 * @param value
 *            the value to be tested
 * @return {@code true} if the input argument matches the
 *         predicate,otherwise {@code false}
 */
boolean test(TreeItem<T> parent, T value);
}
```

And you put it together in your Controller

```
            MyNode myRootNode = myService.getTreeRootNode();

        FilterableTreeItem<MyNode> rootItem = new FilterableTreeItem<>(myRootNode);
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);

        for (MyNode node : myRootNode.getChildren()) {
            FilterableTreeItem<MyNode> item = new FilterableTreeItem<>(node);
            rootItem.getInternalChildren().add(item);
        }


        tree.setRoot(rootItem);


        rootItem.predicateProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(()
                -> TreeItemPredicate.<MyNode> create(myNode
                        -> myNode.isStyled() == hide.getValue())
                , hide));
```

hide is a SimpleBooleanProperty. My node has a boolean property styled.

```
private final BooleanProperty hide = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
```

The Code simply allows to hide the stlyed nodes or the not styled ones.
I know it is stupid, but I just made a test