# JavaFx: How to hide the value of a CheckBoxTreeItem?

Tags: javafx

How to hide the value of a CheckBoxTreeItem?

```
mfbs.add(new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>(mfb.userId, new Label(mfb.userId + "-"  + mfb.name), true));
```

The Label should be the caption of the CheckBoxTreeItem and the first argument `mfb.userId` should not show up at all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This answer helps you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121384/javafx-how-to-disable-one-item-in-checkboxtreeitem

Comment: In your link, the item is **disabled**, but i don't want the first argument to be shown. For now, it's visible next to the second argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a custom cell factory to your TreeView that disables the text:

```
TreeView<String> treeView;
CheckBoxTreeItem<String> root = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("Not Visible", new Label("Visible"));
treeView.setRoot(root);
treeView.setCellFactory(e -> new CustomCheckBoxTreeCell());

public class CustomCheckBoxTreeCell extends CheckBoxTreeCell<String>{

    public CustomCheckBoxTreeCell() {}

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if(!empty){    
            setText(null);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all who have contributed!!

Comment: I've tried this approach with a `TreeItem<org.sparx.Package>` which does not work but I don't know why ...?

Answer (score 0):

I am not Java FX expert but I have worked with Swing API. What my research after your question showed is if you want to make your TreeItem visible/invisible, you should add or remove it.

```
parentTreeItem.getChildren().add(treeItem); // makes visible    
parentTreeItem.getChildren().remove(treeItem); //makes invisible
```

### Edit

If you want to hide only the value of the item, not the whole item, there are things you can make;

- Save the value in a variable (or database or file if you want that it is persistent) and use it when you need it. (After that, you can apply my solution above)
- Make the colour of the text same as the colour of the background.

Comment: No, not remove completely, just the **value**

Comment: You can remove the item and add again without value?

Comment: But i need the value, it just must not be visible.

Answer (score -1):

Apply this css style to your treeView:

```
.tree-view, .tree-cell {      
 -fx-text-fill: transparent;
}
```